# Request form leads to error 405 Method Not Allowed in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to set up a flask app which logs the user in and then prompts them with the segmentation page. The text box has then to be filled in by the user and upon submitting it, the text gets processed. Finally, the user should be logged out automatically.
However, I get a '405 Method Not Allowed' error when reaching the segmentation page.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, Response, session, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'super secret key'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    """
    Sets up home page.

    """
    
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route("/login", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    """
    Login page to retrieve

    """

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['nm']
        session['user'] = user
        return redirect(url_for("my_form_post"))
    else:
        if 'user' in session:
            return redirect(url_for('my_form_post'))
        return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/segmentation')
def my_form_post(methods = ['GET','POST']):
    """
    Sets up input text box and executes relevant action.

    """

    if 'user' in session:
        render_template('segment.html')
        user = session['user']

        if request.method == 'POST':
            text = request.form['text']
            # This function has no return argument
            save_in_directory(text)
            return redirect(url_for('logout'))
        else:
            return render_template('segment.html')
    
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.pop('user', None)
    return redirect(url_for('submitted'))

@app.route("/sent")
def submitted():
    return render_template('success.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

The segment.html template is as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block title%}Login Page{% endblock%}

{% block content%}
<body>

    <p style="font-family: Helvetica; margin-left: 1.2em;"><b>Please, introduce the path:</b></p>
</body>

<form method="POST" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-style:italic; margin-left: 1.2em;" action="/segmentation">
    <input name="text" size = 150>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<p style="font-size:1px;line-height:1;"><br/></p>
{% endblock %}
```

where base.html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='heart.PNG')}}" type="image/png">

<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='welcome.png')}}" style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover'/>

{% block content%}
{% endblock %}

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining the `methods` for your `/segmentation` route as a function parameter which is incorrect, instead you have to define `methods` on `route` decorator like this:

```py
@app.route('/segmentation', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def my_form_post():
    ...
```